# What determines the New Year's reward I get, and (how) can I get them all?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

According to the Prima guide (which is also amazingly unreliable so far), the New Year's countdown gifts from Isabelle vary. To quote their table,

```
Gift                    Value    Note

Bell knickknack         2,000    Korea only.
Berliner                  960    Germany only.
New Year's noodles      3,500    Japan only.
Sparkling cider           800    North America (English and French) and France.
Twelve-grape plate        480    North America (Spanish) and Spain.
```

Is the item you get determined by your *region*, your *language*, or something else entirely? For example, if I'm playing the German cartridge but in English, do I get the Berliner, or the sparkling cider?

Given the note about "North America (English)" etc, I would *assume* that this reward is keyed off the language you're playing the game in. But if that's true, does that mean I can't visit a friend using a different region / language to get their item? (Since my game will still be in English.)

Do the U.K. / other European English speakers get sparkling cider or something else?

The game is also available in Italian and sold in Italy. What reward do Italians/Italian-speakers get?

Comment: If you think my answer helped, don't hesitate to check it as helpful!

Answer (score 4):

I'm playing acnl in spanish (also the region). The other day i invited some japanese friends to my town and they got the christmas socks. If you want those presents from other region, just find some friends in other countries and ask them to invite you.

Answer (score 3):

The gift you get from Isabelle is determined by your region, just like how you get the limited-time items from the post office. Regarding to your second question, if you visit a friend from a different region, you cannot receive that region's New Year's reward, unless your friend manually drops the New Year's reward on the ground. For your third question, the U.K. and all those other countries outside North America get different prizes. As for the fourth question, it certainly cannot be answered by me. I even tried researching it online, and no successful links have showed up. I hope this helped!

Comment: why did you want to know what prizes italians got?

Comment: Italy is notably absent from the partial table in the question, there's no prize listed.

Comment: yes, but he asked what prize do italians get.

Comment: Yes, because the information is missing from the Prima guide and he wants to complete the table.

Comment: But there are no websites where they explain the prize people from Italy get.

Comment: exactly. See what I mean?

Comment: Actually, I don't at all. The information clearly exists somewhere in the universe; have an Italian person change their date to midnight and see what they get. It's a perfectly valid question for this site.

Comment: So let someone who is Italian answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your region,  like the items you get from the post office, the are limited edition according to the events that are happening that month/season. If you go to a pals town you will not receive their new year's gift but if they drop it on the pavement then you can get it that way although I suppose you can change your region on system settings, I am French and I changed my system settings to Spain and I received different gifts, so you could do it that way. :) Hope this helped x